# How to add new font family on TinyMCE text editor ? I tried using "font_formats:" but it does not work

Tags: html, jquery

//Iskoola Pota (Body CS);Iskoola Pota (Headings CS)   - those fonts what i want to add newlyy

tinymce.init({
selector: 'textarea#txt_content',

force_p_newlines: false,
force_br_newlines : true,
force_p_newlines : false,
forced_root_block: '',
height: 500,
font_formats: "Arial,Arial Black;Comic Sans MS,Courier New,Tahoma;Georgia;Helvetica;Iskoola Pota (Body CS);Iskoola Pota (Headings CS);Segoe UI;Sans-Serif;Impact;Tamil Arial Unicode Us font;Times New Roman;Verdana",
content_style: " body { font-family: Verdana; }",
});